# Apply regex expression to a json response data

Tags: javascript, json, regex

Scenario client make a GET request the response is in a JSON format like this one

```
     var data = {
    "enabled": true,
    "state": "schedule",
    "schedules": [
        {
        "rule": {
        "start": "2014-06-29T12:36:26.000",
        "end": "2014-06-29T12:36:56.000",
        "recurrence": [
        "RRULE:FREQ=MINUTELY"
        ]
        },
        "wifi_state_during_rule": "disabled",
        "end_state": "enabled"
        }
    ],
    "calculated_wifi_state_now": "disabled",
    "time_of_next_state_change": [
        "2014-07-08T18:56:56.000Z",
        "2014-07-08T18:57:56.000Z"
    ]
};
```

For the purpose of this example I stored the result in a variable called "data".
My regex Expressions is:

```
checkPattern = /"\w+\"(?=:)/ //all keys "keyname": ...
```

The basic ideia here its just to get the keynames besides being inside of and object or array...since the definition of keyname's in JSON is "keyname": that's why I'm trying to use the above regex expression.

I even thought about doing this with a recursive function but is not working.

Comment: Why use regex for this? Json strings can easily be turned into actual objects in javascript, c#, Java, and many other languages. There's really no need to use regex. So please elaborate on the need for regex or do research to turn it into an object. The info is out there.

Comment: The point here is not using a regex or not.
I want to extract just the names even thought if they are nested.
I used a regexp for testing purposes

Answer (score 1):

You never should parse non-regular structures with regular expressions.

Just collect what you want from parsed json object.
*Just run `data = JSON.parse(json_string)` for parse it*

```
function getKeysRecursive(obj) {
  var result = [];
  for (var key in obj) {
    result.push(key);
    if (typeof obj[key] == 'object') {
       result = result.concat(getKeysRecursive(obj[key]));
    }
  }
  return result;
}

getKeysRecursive(({
    "enabled": true,
    "state": "schedule",
    "schedules": [
        {
        "rule": {
        "start": "2014-06-29T12:36:26.000",
        "end": "2014-06-29T12:36:56.000",
        "recurrence": [
        "RRULE:FREQ=MINUTELY"
        ]
        },
        "wifi_state_during_rule": "disabled",
        "end_state": "enabled"
        }
    ],
    "calculated_wifi_state_now": "disabled",
    "time_of_next_state_change": [
        "2014-07-08T18:56:56.000Z",
        "2014-07-08T18:57:56.000Z"
    ]
}))

// ["enabled", "state", "schedules", "0", "rule", "start", "end", "recurrence", "0", "wifi_state_during_rule", "end_state", "calculated_wifi_state_now", "time_of_next_state_change", "0", "1"]
```

You can filter them, sort, exclude numeric keys... All what you need.

Comment: Thanks sir, thats what I really needed.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you all of the `keys` as the matches:

`\"(\w+)(?:\"\:)`

https://regex101.com/r/iM9wB3/2

Edited to work with multiple `keys` on one line.

Comment: This doesn't work if there are multiple keys on one line. The `+` is too greedy.

Answer (score 0):

You wont need a regular expression for this . Javascript has a built in function to extract Object key names .

**Example :**

Use Object.keys();

```
 var data = {
    "enabled": true,
    "state": "schedule",
    "schedules": [
        {
        "rule": {
        "start": "2014-06-29T12:36:26.000",
        "end": "2014-06-29T12:36:56.000",
        "recurrence": [
        "RRULE:FREQ=MINUTELY"
        ]
        },
        "wifi_state_during_rule": "disabled",
        "end_state": "enabled"
        }
    ],
    "calculated_wifi_state_now": "disabled",
    "time_of_next_state_change": [
        "2014-07-08T18:56:56.000Z",
        "2014-07-08T18:57:56.000Z"
    ]
};
```

**Then**

```
console.log(Object.keys(data));
```

**should print**

`["enabled","state","schedules","calculated_wifi_state_now","time_of_next_state_change"]`

Proof: http://codepen.io/theConstructor/pen/zBpWak

**Now all of your object keys are stored in an array ..**

Hope this helps